# Overwrite save method with conversion from float to string

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-2.2

I'm using [django-mapbox-location-field](https://pypi.org/project/django-mapbox-location-field/) and I need to save automatically the data from `LocationField()` into another field named `coordinates`.

This is my model:

```
class AddPoint(models.Model):
    point = LocationField()
    coordinates = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        lat = self.point[0]
        lon = self.point[1]
        lon_lat = str(lon) + ', ' + str(lat)
        self.coordinates = lon_lat
        super(AddPoint, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Everytime I try to add a point in admin panel I see this error:

> could not convert string to float:
>   '1.110756623730225,17.0771352648959'

I don't understand why happen this. In the save method float is converted to string and not viceversa, moreover coordinates is a char field.

Comment: the string `'1.110756623730225,17.0771352648959'`  is not a float but two comma seperated floats in form of a string - your save seems to want only one float - not two komma seperated ones.... you probably need to give it only lat or lon or a list of floaty-strings - not sure, your code is incomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to indication of @Patrick Artner I've solved the problem.

The solution is this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    lat = self.point[0]
    lon = self.point[1]
    lon_lat = str(str(lon) + ', ' + str(lat))
    self.coordinates = lon_lat
    super(AddPoint, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```