# GeoDjango: ValueError, could not convert string to float

Tags: python, django, django-models, mapbox, geodjango

Yesterday I had the same problem with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58353037/overwrite-save-method-with-conversion-from-float-to-string) simple model and I've managed to solve the problem.

Today I've modified the following **model**:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

from mapbox_location_field.models import LocationField

class IllegalDumpCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(
        max_length=50,
        unique=True,
    )
    description = models.TextField(
        max_length=500,
    )


class IllegalDumpGeo(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(
        'Username',
        max_length=50,
    )
    user_name_email = models.EmailField(
        'Email',
        max_length=254,
    )
    description = models.TextField(
        max_length=500,
    )
    image_1 = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='%Y/%m/%d',
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    image_2 = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='%Y/%m/%d',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    image_3 = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='%Y/%m/%d',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    volume_extension = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    link = models.URLField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    waste_type = models.ForeignKey(
        IllegalDumpCategory,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    geom = models.PointField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    location = LocationField()


    def __int__(self):
        return self.pk

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        lat = self.location[0]
        lon = self.location[1]
        self.geom = Point(x=lon, y=lat, srid=4326)
        super(IllegalDumpGeo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def coordinates(self):
        return str(self.geom.x) + ', ' + str(self.geom.y)
```

I'm trying to add some points by admin panel but I see this error again:

> ```
> ValueError could not convert string to float:
> '6.01245266838146,-10.16992187499897'
> ```

Why is this happening?

**Traceback [here](https://pastebin.com/4pWWphSV)**

Comment: Can you share the entire traceback using pastebin etc ? And paste the link here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is actually a bug in django-mapbox-location-field

Edit line 6 of this file:
mapbox_location_field/widgets.py
and change it to:

`def parse_tuple_string(tuple_string):
     return tuple(map(float, tuple_string[1:-1].split(",")))`

Note I removed the space after the comma in the split method.

That fixes it.
I think i should send in a PR

Answer (score 0):

Well seems a bit odd but looking at the Traceback I think I found the issue:

> ```
> File "/home/max/Django/gealogos/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mapbox_location_field/widgets.py"
> in parse_tuple_string
>   6.     return tuple(map(float, tuple_string[1:-1].split(", ")))
> ```

The `tuple(map(float, tuple_string[1:-1].split(", ")))` method tries to split the input by `', '` (a comma followed by **a space**) but you are passing the following lan_lon: `'6.01245266838146,-10.16992187499897'` which does not have a space after the comma and therefore the `split` does not function as expected, resulting in trying to cast the full string `'6.01245266838146,-10.16992187499897'` as a `float()`.

You need to find and fix the part of your code that creates the lat_lon string (cannot find it in your question, therefore, I cannot help more. It may be a part of the `widget` maybe?) to include the space after the comma between the coords:

```
'lon_coord,<space>lat_coord'
```

Should result in this string for your case:

```
'6.01245266838146, -10.16992187499897'
```

Comment: Unfortunately that part is a part of mapbox-location-field package. Maybe this is a bug? What do you think about?

Comment: I'm thinking to develop a widget myself, is the first time that I do this. Al that I want is put a point on a map using a form. I'm trying to do this since a month, before with OpenLayers ad now with MapBox https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58063527/how-to-geolocate-user-that-fill-up-a-form

Comment: @MassimilianoMoraca I don't have experience with that particular library, but you can create an issue in their repository if you think this is a bug. The other (and a bit harder) solution is to create a custom widget as you said.